# Exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ where $A \cap (c + \mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$, where $A$ has Lebesgue measure $0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Does there exist $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cap (c + \mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$, where $c + \mathbb{Q} = \{c + x : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rational numbers?

Answer (score 2):

First we see that $\mu ( A- \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ indeed, $A- \mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}A-q$ therefore

$$\mu ( A- \mathbb{Q} ) =\mu (    \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}A-q ) \leq \sum _{q\in \mathbb{Q}} \mu(A-q    )=0$$

So since $A-\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero there is a $c\not \in A-\mathbb{Q}$ therefore 
$$A\cap (c + \mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset.$$

Comment: Hey @clark, do you mind clarifying why you can choose a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ where $c \not\in A - \mathbb{Q}$ since $\mu(A \setminus \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ which then satisfies the claim? Thanks.

Comment: @Darkdub Here $A-\mathbb{Q}=\{a-q|q\in \mathbb{Q},a\in A\}$. Also notice $A\cap(c+\mathbb{Q})$ is non-empty iff $c\in A-\mathbb{Q}$.